# java code for producer/consumer not able to connect kafka in docker setup

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have built a docker image for kafka(wurstmeister/kafka-docker). Inside docker container I am able to create topic, produce messages and consume messages using the builtin shell scripts. Now I am using code hosted at https://github.com/mapr-demos/kafka-sample-programs to connect to kafka broker from my host machine. After building and running the program nothing happens and program stucks. I guess producer.send is not able to connect to kafka broker. Any help is appreciated

Comment: In order to check if it is a networking issue, can you try to telnet the ports where the zookeeper/brokers are running? To do so: "telnet <zookeeper-address> 2181" and "telnet <broker-address> 9092".

Comment: @jose.goncabel I am able to telnet zookeeper but not the broker from my host machine. How this can be corrected

Comment: I would like to help you, but I have no previous experience with Docker networking, as far as I can tell you, you are facing a networking issue. However I would recommend you to rewrite your question making clear how your structure looks like. Where the zookeeper, brokers, consumers and producers are running, within the docker container or out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that both the `consumer.properties` and the `producer.properties` files in that project specify `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092`.

Since you cannot connect to the dockerized kafka service using `localhost:9092`, you might try finding the IP address of the docker container, by using, for example, `docker inspect kafka | grep IPA` (assuming that the name of your container is `kafka`).  Then replace `localhost` with that IP address in those two properties files.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ches/kafka docker image. Have a look at the explanation of KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME.